# Comunicação entre software de relatórios em JAVA e software principal em PHP

Tags: php, java

Pensei muito se abriria a pergunta ou não (pode ser fora de escopo ou ampla ou baseada em opiniões), mas como estou com muitas dúvidas em relação a utilização de uma estrutura correta e que atenda a minha necessidade decidi abrir.

**Vamos a minha necessidade.**

**Sistema de relatórios:**

Temos um software para geração de relatórios (`JAVA`), ele não possuí API para renderização do relatório no PHP.
*Todos os clientes* terão acesso a ele. (cada cliente será diferenciado por uma chave única) 
Precisamos acessar esses relatórios através de uma `URL` passando parâmetros, o que poderia trazer transtornos por tentativas de acessar informação indevida...

**Segurança:**

Quando o usuário fizer login no sistema em PHP ele ganhará uma chave única que seria armazenada em uma tabela `MEMORY` e ao sair essa chave seria eliminada.

Toda vez que ele acessar um relatório essa chave seria passada para validação no outro sistema antes de abrir o relatório. Afinal o usuário não gostaria de fazer login novamente quando entrasse nesse sistema... e também passamos a chave única para cada cliente.

*Ou seja até agora temos três parâmetros:* 
`exemplo.com/relatorios?relatorio=teste&cliente=teste&chave_acesso=teste`

**A principal questão:**

1. Não teria alguma forma melhor de implementar a segurança entre esses dois softwares sem precisar usar parâmetros pela URL?
2. Caso usasse a url, na questão de armazenar a chave em uma tabela `MEMORY`, quais seriam suas vantagens/desvantagens?

Comment: Recomendo fortemente essa lib:

https://github.com/geekcom/phpjasper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, existem formas melhores, afinal qualquer pessoa poderia ver o parâmetro na URL no navegador ou em um log de acessos e saberia o "segredo" daquele usuário, que acaba funcionando como uma senha.

Uma maneira simples, mas ainda não 100% segura é gerar uma nova chave aleatória por relatório, pois mesmo que alguém consiga ver aquele relatório copiando a URL, a brecha de segurança será muito menor do que permitir o acesso a todos os relatórios.

Outra alternativa seria que o sistema em Java expusesse um web service para o sistema em PHP. Então o usuário solicitaria o relatório para o sistema em PHP, o qual invocaria o web service correspondente e retornaria o relatório para o usuário.

Há duas formas básicas de repassar o conteúdo do relatório:

1. Instruir o sistema em Java a armazenar o relatório em disco, então você lê do PHP e joga o stream de bytes como retorno para o usuário. Isto é relativamente simples, pois o PHP implementa uma função pronta: [`fpassthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php).
2. O webservice Java retorna diretamente o stream de bytes e o PHP apenas repassa para o usuário.

A principal vantagem dessa abordagem é que o segundo sistema é transparente para o usuário, ele não terá ciência de sua existência, portanto ele não precisa estar aberto para acesso externo e seria um nó a menos para se preocupar com a questão de segurança. Em suma: menos exposição.

As desvantagens incluem um pouco mais de trabalho para implementar e uma carga maior para o sistema em PHP, pois este precisará chamar o web service, recuperar o retorno e repassar para o usuário. Se o servidor já estiver sobrecarregado esta pode não ser uma opção.

Comment: Muito obrigado, abriu meu leque de possibilidades, além de apresentar opções que eu não havia pensado antes. Vou pesquisar a respeito e ver se consigo implementar a solução aqui.